# does a Taylor series converge to f(x) if the radius of convergence is $R=\infty$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

If I want to check whether a Taylor series converges to its function f(x). Is it enough to check if the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is infinite?

Or do I have to use the remainder theorem and show the remainder converges to zero?

---

**Edit**: I'm still confused about convergence of taylor series.
If I have a function f(x) which is defined on $x\in ]-R,R[$, and I found it's taylor series T(x) with a radius of convergence R.
Doesn't the taylor series converge to f(x)?

Why do I necessarily need to check that the remainder $R_n(x)$ converges to zero for it to be true?

In other words, what does the taylor series converge to, if it doesn't converge to f(x)? (Because I thought if a taylor series was convergent it would always be towards f(x)? But that's probably where the whole issue is?).

Comment: $f(X)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x >0$ $f(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$. All the terms in the Taylor series are $0$ for this function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, but what if I work with regular functions like e^x, cosx, ln(x), sinx*cosx, etc. If I found the radius of convergence to be the same as the interval that the original function is defined. Would the series converge?

Comment: For $\mathrm e^x, \sin x,\cos x, \sinh x,\cosh x$, it does converge.

Comment: @Bernard but can I conclude that because the radius of convergence is infinite? Or that isn't enough?

Comment: @sjm23 If by "normal" you mean "analytic", then yes by definition.

Comment: @smj23: Actually the definition of the functions I mentioned is that they *are* the sum of the corresponding series. If the radius of convergence were  finite, they would be defined on a finite interval, that's all.

Comment: @Gae.S - Thank you for your response. But I'm a bit confused about this. If a function f(x)'s taylor series is convergent on some interval (could be finite or infinite radius of convergence), but it doesn't converge to f(x). What does it converge to then? 

Because I thought (I think it says so in my book) that if a taylor series converges it converges to the function f(x)?

Comment: @Bernard See my question above^^

Comment: ,, Good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinitely differentiable function of a real variable is not necessarily the sum of its Taylor series. I'll give  an example below. It it is the sum of its Taylor series, it is called an *analytic function*. Contrary to the real case, a function  of a complex variable which is differentiable is  infinitely differentiable *and* analytic.

*Example* of a non-analytic infinitely differentiable function of a real variable:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\mathrm e^{-1/x^2}&\;\text{ if }x\ne 0,\\ 0&\;\text{ if }x=0.  
\end{cases}$$
It is easy to show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$, hence its Taylor series at $0$ is $0,\:\ne f(x)$ if $x\ne 0$.

Comment: Arrh, that makes sense now. I study physics, and have always been told that you can just approximate a function by a taylor polynomial. But I guess that's only true, if the taylor series converges to the function on the interval you want to approximate the function? 

So I am right, if I say that in general a taylor polynomial will be a bad approximation of a non-analytic function. And in theory, whenever I use taylor polynomials of a function, I should check if the taylor series converges to that function (In the interval I want to approximate)?

Comment: And also, so the radius of convergence only tells me that the taylor series converges to some function. But it doesn't tell me which one. So if I want to make sure it converges to f(x), I should check if the remainder converges to zero?

Comment: Yes, absolutely (unless you have some good reason to know the function is analytic).